# How to access serveralias in local network from other device

Tags: android, apache, localhost, alias, virtualhost

Maybe I'm typing the wrong words by google but I' totally lost and can't a solution.
On my work we all access our projects through server alias like project.company.local

But when I'm at home with my company notebook I can't reach my websites aliases from e.g. my smartphone or any other device at home. Although they are all in the same network.

I have Ubuntu and Apache on my notebook.

My etc/hosts has
127.0.0.1  projectA.company.local

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your hosts file only works for the computer itself, not other machines on the network. Your work must have the appropriate entries set up on the DNS server. You could just access a site on your home computer, from other devices on the network, using the IP address of your computer, instead of a host name, if it's just one site. Otherwise perhaps your router will allow adding DNS entries for the local network. If you're going to do that, you'd also best set up a static IP address for your home computer so it doesn't change. Hope that is enough info for you to get it sorted.